# Regular expression javascript insert space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression in my javascript:

```
var name = '#tee name test ';
var title = name.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
```

This generate this title:

```
teenametest
```

But I'd want this:

```
tee name test
```

How can I allow space but remove other characters like '#'?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var title = name.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
```

To this:

```
var title = name.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi,'');
```

You need to tell the regex not to replace the spaces.

If you need to remove the last space, you can use the `string.trim` function.

If you still want to use regex to remove the last space as well, you can use:

```
var title = name.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]|\s+$/gi,'');
```

Comment: yes this works like a charm! thanks +1 as soon as possible I accept it!

Comment: `\s` is the whitespace character group! This is not the same like a simple space... I'd go with `/[^a-z0-9 ]| *$/`.

Comment: Better use: /[^a-z0-9\s]|\ +(?=$)/

Comment: @Christoph Could you perhaps explain why would it be better? I mean, what real risk is there that `\s` introduces that a whitespace doesn't? What if there are tabs and other such characters that should not be removed as well?

Comment: @Floyd yup, that takes care of multiple spaces if there are more. Gonna add it, thank you :)

Comment: @Jerry well, I guess this probably is up to the OP's requirements. However, you should at least note that `\s` does not represent "the space character" but rather the whole family of whitespace characters. And a lookahead is not necessary for the `$`. It just slows down the regex.

Comment: @Christoph Okay, and yup, I'm not sure why I used it there... Thanks!